# Pull content from slack as JSON

Tags: node.js, json, automation, slack, dashboard

I am part of a company slack workspace, we get alerts from all the systems that we have deployed (via various channels). I was looking for a way to extract the information out via json and create a node app to show the alerts as dashboards, so if a service is down for more than 10 minutes it triggers an alert, etc.
I want to know if there is a way to do that.
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by creating a custom app.

**Process Flow:**

1. Create an app with relevant scopes
2. Subscribe to `message` event
3. Add your bot to the channels, where alerts are received

You app will listen to the `message` event & the payload of the event will contain details of message. You can write your business process based on that.

**Reading Materials**

 https://api.slack.com/apis/connections/events-api

 https://api.slack.com/tutorials/hello-world-bolt

Comment: Thank You, I will try that. The only issue I know I will face it that I will not be able to create the app as I am not the admin for it

Comment: You'll need the help of your slack admins. May be they can help you build the bot as well.

Comment: Can you mark this answer as accepted, if it helped you?